# AWS Custom Domain Name Mapping - Cached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When I create "API mappings" for "Custom domain name" I get 403 **intermittently**.

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Response header: x-amzn-ErrorType = ForbiddenException

I would say it is roughly 50/50. Half of the time, it works just fine.

Additional info:

- Custom domain endpoint type: Regional
- Directly calling HTTPApi endpoint works all the time (https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod)
- I'm testing using Postman and custom app. Both give the same intermittent behavior.
- More than a day passed since the base path mappings we created. I would think any cache issues should have been cleared by now.
- I've been working on this stuff for the past 2 months and until Jul 23, all changes to basepath mapping took effect immediately.
- It doesn't matter if I create mapping using CLI/web console/CloudFormation the behavior is the same.
- There is a guide to troubleshoot 403 but both instances of "x-amzn-ErrorType" = "ForbiddenException" response header mentioned there do not apply in my case https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden
- The guide doesn't mention all possible scenarios for 403. If you try to access random basepath that is no defined in the mappings you'll also get 403 instead of expected "not found".
- For example, if I hit my custom domain mapping in Postman 3 times, 2 could be 200 and third attempt 403. The Postman Console shows that all 3 times it went to the same IP address (based on whois some EC2 instance) probably for Route53. Not sure but I can't rule out some AWS internal load balancing / caching issues.
- I've deleted all CloudFormation stacks and recreated custom domain name, apis and mappings. Same issue.

Questions:

- Does anyone experience the above in the past or now?
- Does anyone know if of any documentation that might shed some light on this? I read all the official docs and random blogs I could find that mention base path mappings and none mention any caching issues.
- Anything else you would try in my place?

Thanks,